# The value of a constant changes when I save a js file or refresh the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I have this react component:

```
import "./App.scss";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const quotesDbUrl =
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json";

function App() {
    const [quotesArray, setQuotesArray] = useState(null);

    const fetchQuotes = async (url) => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const parsedJSON = await response.json();
        setQuotesArray(parsedJSON.quotes);
        console.log(quotesArray);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchQuotes(quotesDbUrl);
    }, [quotesDbUrl]);


    return (
        <div></div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

When I `console.log(quotesArray)` on the `fetchQuotes` function, I get `null`. If I edit the file, say `console.log(parsedJSON.quotes)`, I get the value I expected (an array). I can go back to `console.log(quotesArray)` and I get the same array. If I refresh the browser, I get null again.

I have no idea what's going on, I just want to setQuotesArray to an array feched from the Url. any clues?

Answer (score 1):

console.log(quotesArray) and console.log(parsedJSON.quotes) are different, and what you are seeing has to do with closures and asynchronous nature of setState calls.

When the function is first created, a closure is created around quotesArray at the time of render (before your function is called). At this point in time, quotesArray will be null as you initialized it

```
const fetchQuotes = async (url) => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const parsedJSON = await response.json();
    setQuotesArray(parsedJSON.quotes);
    console.log(quotesArray);
};
```

is equivalent to

```
const fetchQuotes = async (url) => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const parsedJSON = await response.json();
    setQuotesArray(parsedJSON.quotes); //setting state is async, this will not be available in quotesArray until the component rerendered, and this function is recreated.
    console.log(null); //quotesArray was null when the fetchQuotes closure was created
};
```

When the function is called the first time, and you log quotesArray, it will display null. parsedJSON is a local variable which is updated within the scope of the function, hence it will display your data.

If you want to see quotesArray updating, you can create a useEffect with this as its dependency to see this within your App component.

```
   useEffect(() => {
       console.log(`quotesArray updated: ${quotesArray}`)
   },[quotesArray])
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. So I understand that setQuotesArray is actually working, but before that, quotesArray is initialized as null. If I console.log(quotesArray) outside of the function, I first get undefined and then the array. But I can't do anything with quotesArray (use it in my application) because I always first get this initial value.

So is there a way to use this constant with the value assigned in fetchQuotes, or I can only use the null value? That wouldn't make much sense

Comment: It is a good idea to initialize state to something which represents the data you will be using it for. With arrays, typically `useState([])`. This would allow array functions to work without throwing errors like `cannot read property 'map' of undefined'. initialization of state is done before the first render, so in this case, if you console log within the App, you should get an empty array and then the data after the async call finishes.